# When text wraps in HTML paragraph, align to first non-whitespace character on first line with *only* css

Tags: css

I have a paragraph of text as follows:

```
<p>

&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp; In this respect, the conceptual structure of the Act is something like a pyramid. The pyramid shape illustrates the way the income tax law is organised, moving down from the central or core provisions at the top of the pyramid, to general rules of wide application and then to the more specialised topics.

</p>
```

At the moment it renders to this:

> In this respect, the conceptual structure of the Act is something like a pyramid. The pyramid shape illustrates the way the income tax law is organised, moving down from the central or core provisions at the top of the pyramid, to general rules of wide application and then to the more specialised topics.

I want it to render like this:

```
                   In this respect, the conceptual structure of the Act is something like a 
                   pyramid. The pyramid shape illustrates the way the income tax law is  
                   organised, moving down from the central or core provisions at the top of 
                   the pyramid, to general rules of wide application and then to the more 
                   specialised topics.
```

Only using CSS!

#### Backstory

I am converting Markdown files to HTML. These files are in source control. The Markdown files are already indented for me using `&ensp;` chars. I also want clean commit logs so I want to keep each `<p>` on a single line.

#### Edit

Here is a gist of a section from one of the Markdown documents: https://gist.github.com/vjpr/5378401

Basically I want to

- avoid the use of inline html in my Markdown documents.
- allow Markdown documents to be viewed on GitHub with indentation.
- allow the same Markdown document to be viewed with a custom stylesheet and keep wrapping paragraphs at same level of indentation as first non-whitespace char as show.

Comment: Dude, you're doing `margin-left` wrong. `:P`. What were you thinking?

Comment: So, I'm not sure what you were thinking with those en spaces, but if you can, get rid of them, and use `margin-left` or `padding-left` to control the indentation on the web-page.

Comment: @vaughan How many pages you need to change? Is it a one off? If yes, then easy is a manual intervention. Else, use jquery/ javascript replace strings. Load it on body tags so it loads quick. use the string to remove just `&ensp;`

Comment: @ŠimeVidas There is a reason I stressed the point of "only using CSS". Here is why: This is the output I get from a Markdown to HTML compiler. I do not have control over this compiler - it will be whatever Github uses. 

I could add `<p style="...">` for every paragraph but that would greatly clutter my Markdown file which I am not willing to do. I have thousands of files to compile and they already have the spaces inserted for indentation. I could add the spaces for each line but as I said earlier I would prefer to keep paragraphs on a single line in version control for nice commit logs.

Comment: @Mee I have thousands of documents, not really possible. The viewer for these files is Github.

Comment: @vaughan But the `&ensp;`s are in your Markdown source code, correct? Or is the GitHub Markdown-to-HTML compiler adding them? Please provide a link to one of your Markdown files, if you can.

Comment: @vaughan Is all of your pages the same? Also, are you looking to have the same `style` for all your text? I still think that the best thing would be a Javascript replace.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas https://gist.github.com/vjpr/5378401 - They are in my code. The biggest constraint is avoiding the use of inline html in my Markdown files.

Comment: @vaughan Why aren't you using Markdown syntax for lists?

Comment: @Mee take a look at the gist here: https://gist.github.com/vjpr/5378401

Comment: I can't replace the &ensp; using javascript. I have tried using the Hex code of the same tag but can make it working. [Anyone wants to have a go?](http://jsfiddle.net/NzUtM/2/) I'm not good in javascript lol.

Comment: @Mee str.replace '\u2002', ''.

Comment: @vaughan Why do you have en spaces instead of regular spaces in your Markdown?

Comment: I can't use Javascript in the solution. Only CSS. @Fabrizio's answer seems the best so far.

Comment: Thanks everyone! The SO community is amazing - I need to get involved more often. I've accepted Fabrizio's answer - reasons in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a combination of padding-left and negative text-indent, e.g.

```
p{
    padding-left:18em;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-indent :-9em;
}
```

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NzUtM/1

Feel free to adjust padding and indent as you need.

Comment: What if other text has different "layout"? Won't it affect? E.g text all the way to the left?

Comment: I am accepting this answer. It is similar to @Vucko's comment above - but does it all in the one selector.

This allows me to ensure all wrapped lines are beyond the first line. It can't line them up with the first letter exactly, but the result is acceptable.